# Index not resetting

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, list-comprehension, reset

I have a list comprehension and within it, I call a function, passing to it two arguments. Within the function, I have another list comprehension that gives me a list of DataFrames.

I have to clean the data in each DataFrame, so I use a for loop to go through every DataFrame in the list. In each iteration, I do whatever I need to do, one of the things being resetting the index of each DataFrame. I put a print statement outside of the function just to make sure I get everything the way I need them to look, but the indices are not being reset. Why isn't it being reset?

```
def function(xls, a_list):
    # a_list is a list of strings
    df_list = [pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=a) for a in a_list]

    for df in df_list:
        df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
        df['Meal'] = df['Meal'].fillna(method='ffill')

        # RIGHT HERE 
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

    return df_list

# ------------------------------------

list_of_df = [function(xls, monthly_sheets) for xls, monthly_sheets in zip(xls_files, sheet_names) if monthly_sheets]
```

As an example, this is what I am getting:

```
        Col1        Col2
0        a            f
1        b            g
4        c            h
7        d            i
8        e            j
```

What I want is this:

```
        Col1        Col2
0        a            f
1        b            g
2        c            h
3        d            i
4        e            j
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the other operations inside the Loop successful?  Do the dataframes all get altered inside df_list?

Comment: Yup, everything works except for the reset_index. Turns out I need to include 'inplace=True' to modify the dataframe in place as opposed to creating a new one. Thanks for taking the time to review my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Use

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

The problem is that `df.reset_index()` **returns** a value if `inplace` is `False`, and you've **assigned** that value to `df`, but then you're not doing anything further with `df`. You're working with a list of dataframes, and that list doesn't include the new **local** `df` that you've just created.

Another alternative would be storing the new `df` in your `df_list`. That feels like more work to me though since pandas already supports inplace arguments for most of their operations.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! It works now :)